# Как сделать что бы каждый файл сохранялся в отдельной папке?

Tags: delphi

Этот код разбивает текст на части и сохраняет в одной папке.

Как сделать что бы каждый файл сохранялся в отдельной папке при разбитии?

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  n,k,j,p,q:integer;
  t,t1:TStringList;
  F1, F2 : File;
  i, SizePart, SizePartAdd : Cardinal;
  Buff : array of Byte;
 begin
  n:=strtoint(Edit1.Text);//количество разбиений
  t:=TStringList.Create;
  if OpenDialog1.InitialDir = '' then begin
    OpenDialog1.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  end;
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then Exit;
  if not FileExists(OpenDialog1.FileName) then begin
    ShowMessage('Указанный файл не найден. Действие отменено.');
    Exit;
  end;

  AssignFile(F1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(F1, 1);

  if FileSize(F1) < N then begin
    ShowMessage('Указанный файл слишком мал. Разбиение отменено.');
    CloseFile(F1);
    Exit;
  end;

  SizePart := FileSize(F1) div N;
  SizePartAdd := FileSize(F1) mod N;
  SetLength(Buff, SizePart);

  for i := 1 to N do begin
    AssignFile(F2, OpenDialog1.FileName + '.part' + IntToStr(i));
    Rewrite(F2, 1);
    BlockRead(F1, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePart);
    BlockWrite(F2, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePart);
    if (i = N) and (SizePartAdd > 0) then begin
      BlockRead(F1, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePartAdd);
      BlockWrite(F2, Pointer(Buff)^, SizePartAdd);

    end;
    CloseFile(F2);
  end;

  CloseFile(F1);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

Как составить путь для файла - зависит от ваших требований. Можно, например, так:

```
somePath :=
  ExtractFilePath(OpenDialog1.FileName) + 'part' + IntToStr(i) + PathDelim +
  ExtractFileName(OpenDialog1.FileName);
```

а далее:

```
  ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(somePath)); // Убедиться, что папка создана
  AssignFile(F2, somePath); // или другой способ сохранения файла
```

Comment: Немного не поняла как сделать. Можете подсказать на примере моего кода ? Пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Татьяна Отредактируйте вопрос, напишите какой путь у вас есть и каой должен быть, с примерами.

Comment: Путь, я открываю через opendialog. То есть в той папке где открыт файл там и должны создаваться папки с файлами.